# why the switch to editor keyboard shortcut is not working on my spyder?

Tags: spyder

why the switch to editor keyboard shortcut is not working on my spyder ?

where as switch to console is working !!

cltr + i = switch to console

then why not,

cltr + E = is not switching to editor (predefined in settings)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in newer Spyder, see
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/19374